# How to merge / unite multiple RxJX Observable?

Tags: rxjs, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 with RxJs and i was wonder whether it's a good practice to subscribe to multiple Observables this way, or there is a better approach to merge the responses and later, use their values.

```
// First create a Subscription array to add all the Observables for unsubscribe from them easily
private subs: Subscription[] = [];

// Next , push them
this.subs.push(this.myFirstSub.subscribe(res1 => {
 // Do something.
    this.subs.push(this.myFirstSub.subscribe(res2 => {
    // Do something with res1 and res2...
}))
}))

// Dispose all
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subs.forEach((us) => us.unsubscribe());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to handle multiple subscriptions like that. Composing one single stream is a better practice:

```
private sub: Subscription;

this.sub = this.myFirstSub.pipe(
  tap(res1 => {
    // Do something.
  }),
  mergeMap(() => this.myFirstSub),
  tap(res2 => {
    // Do something with res1 and res2...
  })
)
.subscribe()

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

In your case the `tap` operator could trigger a simple side effect (the operator wouldn't wait for async operations to complete). `mergeMap` subscribes to `this.myFirstSub` and unsubscribes automatically once we complete the outer stream with `this.sub.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Thanks - can i use your example to conditionally subscribe to the second subscription?  suppose the first subscription returns a list of users - and the second subscription check if the current user is logged ...

Comment: yes you can directly consume the result inside `mergeMap`. It's provided as an argument. Then you either subscribe to an observable again or just return an empty stream if you don't want to trigger the callback in the last `tap` operator. Example:  `mergeMap((res1) => res1 ? this.myFirstSub : EMPTY)`